# How can I get spaces to render in my dropdown option label template call?

Tags: matrix, drop-down

**Example**

Let `entry.dropdownOption.label` = "option with spaces"

```
{% for entry in entry.dropdown %}
    {{ entry.dropdownOption.label }}
{% endfor %}
```

renders as in my template: "optionwithspaces"

How can I instead get it to render as "option with spaces"?

Comment: I must be doing something wrong... The .value outputs camelCase as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was happening because i'd set some values for my content and then changed the structure of the field. I just reset the values for my content and all was well.